# Distance between Centroids of the Faces of a Regular Tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I was recently given this question to solve:

In regular tetrahedron $ABCD$, $AB = 1$. What is the distance between the centroids of triangles $ABC$ and $ABD$?

This is how I solved it:

If we set $A = (0, 0, 0)$, $B = (1, 0, 0)$, and correspondingly $C = (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},0)$, then the centroid of $\triangle{ABC}$ is $\frac{A + B + C}{3}$, or $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{6},0)$.

In  $\triangle{ABD}$, the length of the median from $D$ is equal to $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, so the height of the tetrahedron from $D$ to base ${ABC}$ can be found to be $\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}$ using the Pythagorean Theorem.

Knowing that the centroid of $\triangle{ABD}$ lies $\frac{1}{3}$ of the way from the midpoint of $AB$ to $D$, the coordinates of the centroid can be determined as $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{18},\frac{\sqrt{6}}{9})$. Then, using the distance formula the desired length can be found as $\frac{1}{3}$.

However, I wasn't satisfied with this solution because I'm convinced there is a cleaner way to solve this, ideally using Euclidean geometry (or anything without coordinate bashing). Can anyone provide such a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, there is a much simpler approach.

Define $D'$ as the centroid of $\triangle ABC $ and $C'$ as the centroid of $\triangle ABD $.  Draw ray $AD'$ which intersects side $BC $ at point  $D''$.  Likewise draw ray $AC'$ which intersects side $BD $ at point  $C''$.  These rays, of course, include medians of the respective triangular faces in which they lie.

$C''$ and  $D''$ are midpoints of two sides of face $BCD $ whose sides measure one unit, thus $|C''D''|=1/2$.  $\triangle AC'D'$ is similar to $\triangle AC''D''$ with corresponding side ratio $|AC'|/|AC''|=2/3$, thus $|C'D'|=(2/3)(1/2)=1/3$.

Comment: It's not just a regular tetrahedron.  In _any_ trerahedron the distance between the centroids of two faces is one third the length of the side opposite those two faces.  The reader can adapt my argument to prove this more general result.

Answer (score 3):

Construct a cube with side length $\frac {\sqrt 2}{2}$

choose one vertex.  There are 3 vertexes that are diagonally across each face.

Join these 4 vertexes.

You have constructed a regular tetrahedron with side length equal to 1.

See figure.
 [image]

I have marked the centroid of two faces with the little dots.

Now lets move to the top view.... The centroid is $\frac 23$ the distance from the vertex to the opposite edge.  Which means that the distance between the centroid of two faces is $\frac 13$ the lenght of the diagonal of the face.  And we have already discussed that that length is 1.

$\frac 13$

Answer (score 2):

The plane perpendicular to $\overline{AB}$ at its midpoint ($M$) contains edge $\overline{CD}$, creating isosceles $\triangle MBC$ whose legs coincide with altitudes of adjacent faces $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle ABD$.

[image]

It is "known" that the centroid of a triangle lies one-third of the way from a side to its opposite vertex. Consequently, centroids $P$ and $Q$ of the adjacent faces faces trisect $\overline{MC}$ and $\overline{MD}$; by proportionality, $|PQ|=\frac13|CD|$: *The distance between centroids is one-third the side of the tetrahedron.* $\square$